# Is Xsession run by default on Jammy (22.04)?

Tags: 22.04, xserver, unclutter

The context is that I'm attempting to get [`unclutter-xfixes`](https://github.com/Airblader/unclutter-xfixes) to start automatically. As part of its setup, `unclutter` installs a file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90unclutter` with the following contents:

```sh
# /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90unclutter
# This file is sourced by Xsession(5), not executed.

if [ -e /etc/default/unclutter ]
then
    . /etc/default/unclutter
fi

if [ -x /usr/bin/unclutter ] && [ "${START_UNCLUTTER}" = "true" ]
then
    /usr/bin/unclutter ${EXTRA_OPTS} &
fi
```

The file at `/etc/default/unclutter` sets the vars used in the second statement above, which in my case sets `START_UNCLUTTER="true"`, so I would expect unclutter to be started with `X`, but it is not.

I've tried two things to confirm that this file is being sourced:

1. Look at the `Xsession` logs. Per `man 5 Xsession`, "`$HOME/.xsession-errors` ... is where standard output and standard error for Xsession script and all X client processes are directed by default [and] `$TMPDIR/filename` ... is where the X session error file is placed if $HOME/.xsession-errors cannot be opened." However, `sudo find -type f -name "*xsession*"` yields nothing in either `/tmp` or the user's home directory.
2. Do something silly like `touch` a new file in the user's home dir at the end of `90unclutter`. This has no apparent effect.

I see in the description of `man 5 Xsession` that "Some display managers only invoke Xsession when specifically directed to so by the user." `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` indicates that I'm using `gdm3`, but I'm not having any luck determining whether `gdm3` is in fact invoking `Xsession`.

In summary, should I expect files named within `run-parts` constraints under `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` to be sourced by `gdm3` on a default `22.04` installation? If so, why am I not seeing the expected effect of said sourcing, and how can I dig in to confirm what is and isn't happening? If not, what other avenues are open to me to start a process in the GUI context on startup?

---

EDIT: Per @matigo's response, the trouble seems to be that `Xsession` does run under Wayland, so `unclutter-startup` is likewise broken under Wayland. I've filed a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unclutter/+bug/1998720).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 22.04 will run Wayland by default rather than X. You can confirm which display server your system is using with this Terminal command:

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

If you are running Wayland, the response will be `wayland`. Otherwise, it will be `x11`.